# Is my VPS under DDoS atack?

Tags: vps, centos7, ddos

When i run this command on my VPS:

```
netstat -n|grep :80|cut -c 45-|cut -f 1 -d ':'|sort|uniq -c|sort -nr|more
```

i get this result:

```
207 222.73.144.194
 89 191.96.249.54
 58 191.96.249.53
 21 2400
 15 51.255.64.23
  6 143.137.103.251
  3 103.27.72.36
  1 89.180.150.168
  1 66.102.7.137
  1 5.189.170.167
  1 191.181.39.208
  1 183.2.246.218
```

I think this command is showing the number of connections per IP to port 80.

Is this a DDoS atack?

Answer (score 0):

Have you check another aspect (eg. cpu load, network throughput to specific ip(s) using iftop or iptraf)? If there's normal, maybe it's just web/http scanner to your web.

If you're use nginx, you can use [limit_conn](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html) module, to queue the rest of ip(s) if didn't obey your policy.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer but yes, i was under DDOS atack.. im still under DDOS atack.. I am manually blocking suspect ips on iptables... like 200 ips per day... :(